# Why the script saves all the time the same data?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a problem with my php Script that the system runs every minute.

My php-script is this:

```
<?php
$y = date("Y", time());
$m = date("m", time());
$d = date("d", time());
$h = date("H", time());

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("dashboard");

$check_date = mysql_query("SELECT year,month,day FROM serverstats WHERE year='".$y."' && month='".$m."' && day='".$d."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($check_date)==0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO serverstats (year,month,day,h01,h02,h03,h04,h05,h06,h07,h08,h09,h10,h11,h12,h13,h14,h15,h16,h17,h18,h19,h20,h21,h22,h23,h24)
        VALUES (
        '".$y."', '".$m."', '".$d."', NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL
        );
    ") or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    $load = file_get_contents("/proc/loadavg");
    $load = explode( ' ', $load );
    $total_load = $load[0] + $load[1] + $load[2];

    $last_load = mysql_query("SELECT h".$h." FROM serverstats");
    $daten = mysql_fetch_array($last_load);
    $total = $daten["h".$h.""]+$total_load;

    mysql_query("UPDATE serverstats SET h".$h."='".$total."'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE serverstats SET ts ='".time()."'");
}

?>
```

And the database looks like this:
The Timestamp(ts) and the other values are the same, what did I make wrong?
[image]

Comment: Check your where condition in update query.

Comment: You are calling `date()` multiple times. Doesn't that yield different dates when you run this script around midnight?

Comment: @spaceknarf That can be the problem why h24 is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing where condition in update

```
UPDATE serverstats SET ts ='".time()."'"
```

While updating the database it should have where clause .. your sql should be something like\

```
UPDATE serverstats SET ts ='".time()."' Where = 'your condition'"
```

If you miss `where` in update clause .. then all records will get updated ..

**NOTE** please switch to mysqli_* or PDO . mysql_* are no longer officially maintained.

Comment: look like some data just got messed up

Comment: with `WHERE year='".$y."' && month='".$m."' && day='".$d."'` works it, thx.

Comment: @DrewPierce .. OP had missed the where condition while updating the record .. so the corresponding columns of all records were getting updated and hence same data

Comment: i know. i was joking about how he slammed all his rows :>

Comment: @DrewPierce  It happens sometimes at learning stage . this is what learning all about .. make mistakes improve them and learn ..isnt it ? :)

Comment: correct. btw the where clause is also useful in the delete from statement

Comment: @DrewPierce not useful **mandatory** unless u want to lose all of ur data ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the ts is not an "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" field. Having this would make it easier, leaving the ts stuff to the DB.

BUT:

these two statements

```
mysql_query("UPDATE serverstats SET h".$h."='".$total."'");
mysql_query("UPDATE serverstats SET ts ='".time()."'");
```

Will ***always update all records in the table*** - missing where clause.

Try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE serverstats SET h".$h."='".$total."', ts ='".time()."' ". 
            " WHERE year='".$y."' && month='".$m."'` && day='".$d."'");
```

and obviously

```
$last_load = mysql_query("SELECT h".$h." FROM serverstats " . 
" WHERE year='".$y."' && month='".$m."'` && day='".$d."'");
```

since otherwise this is reading the entire table and your taking just an arbitrary first row.

Comment: some idea: if you have a unique (primary) index on day/month/year you may shrink that to an "INSERT INTO ..... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...."

Answer (score 1):

It seems I don't have enough rep to leave comments but as an aside, you're using:

```
$h = date("H", time());
```

Which is in the form of 00 to 23 but the table columns are 01 - 24.

This may become an issue for example at 00:

```
$last_load = mysql_query("SELECT h".$h." FROM serverstats");
...
```

Comment: what is a solution of the problem?

Comment: You could change the column names to match the date format, or code around the difference.